# admin.messaging().sendToDevice() Not working - Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I am getting a successful response from sendToDive() but push notifications are not showing up in android. When sending notifications from the firebase dashboard all work fine.

This is my **firebase cloud function:**

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


export const helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

  const token = request.query.token;

  const payload = {
    notification: {
        title: 'Nueva compra!',
        body: 'Rivisa tu bandeja de ordenes.'
    }
  }

  admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload)
    .then(() => response.send("OK"))
    .catch(() => response.send("FAIL"));
});
```

Also I'm using Ionic 3 to create my app. I'm running this code:

```
ionic cordova platform add android
ionic cordova platform build android --release
```

and testing the app in Android Studio in a real device

Comment: Any solution?, I'm stock with this.